# How to make a custom SpinnerNumberModel power of 2

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I'm trying to make a custom SpinnerNumberModel Class and implement 4 methods, which is getValue(), setValue(), getNextValue(), and getPreviousValue(). it seems i always get error from all those methods when i want to set the stepsize to power of 2.

```
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;

public class MySpinnerModel extends SpinnerNumberModel {

    Number value;
    @Override
    public Object getValue() {
        Object returnValue = Math.pow(2, (Double) super.getValue());
        return returnValue;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(Object value) {
         if ((value == null) || !(value instanceof Number)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("illegal value");
            }
            if (!value.equals(this.value)) {
                this.value = (Double)value;
                fireStateChanged();
            }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getNextValue() {
        Object returnValue = Math.pow(2, (Double) super.getNextValue());
        return returnValue;

    }

    @Override
    public Object getPreviousValue() {
        Object returnValue = Math.pow(2, (Double) super.getPreviousValue());
        return returnValue;
    } 

}
```

Comment: And what's the error that you get?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
 at MySpinnerModel.getValue(MySpinnerModel.java:8)
 at javax.swing.JSpinner.getValue(JSpinner.java:331)
 at javax.swing.JSpinner$DefaultEditor.<init>(JSpinner.java:623)
 at javax.swing.JSpinner$NumberEditor.<init>(JSpinner.java:1199)
 at javax.swing.JSpinner$NumberEditor.<init>(JSpinner.java:1175)
 at javax.swing.JSpinner$NumberEditor.<init>(JSpinner.java:1150)
 at javax.swing.JSpinner.createEditor(JSpinner.java:249)
 at javax.swing.JSpinner.<init>(JSpinner.java:155)

Comment: at Hw5SpinnerModel.<init>(Hw5SpinnerModel.java:11)
 at Hw5SpinnerModel.main(Hw5SpinnerModel.java:27)

Comment: So you cant cast Integer to Double. Define your variable as Double rather than Integer.

Comment: oh yes now its working, but still i think i implemented it the wrong way, when i push the button for increasing or decreasing number in spinner the number doesn't change

Comment: share your SpinnerNumberModel class

Comment: actually the code that i shared above is mySpinnerNumberModel Class

Comment: that's the reason why am asking for SpinnerNumberModel i.e. your super class and what exactly you mean by "when i push the button for increasing or decreasing number in spinner the number doesn't change" is that number field you are talking about? And what method gets called when you press button?

Answer (score 2):

> when i push the button for increasing or decreasing number in spinner the number doesn't change

The problem is you never call `super.setValue()` from your `setValue()` overridden method. Instead you assign the value to class field which is not used anywhere.